# Characterization of a quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Given the space $C^n[0,1]$ of all real functions of class $C^n$ in $[0,1]$, let $\tilde{d}^j := d_\infty(f^{(j)},g^{(j)})$ a pseudometric $(j=1,\dots,n)$ on $C^n[0,1]$.
Here $f^{(j)}$ mean the $j^{th}$ derivative of $f$, and $d_\infty$ is the uniform metric given by $d_\infty(f,g) = \max\{|f(x)-g(x)|: x \in[0,1]\}$.

*Question*:
Characterize the quotient spaces $C^n[0,1]/\tilde{d}^j.$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that the elements of these spaces $C^n[0,1]/\tilde{d}^j$ (for each $j$) are classes of equivalence given by $\{y \in C^n: d_\infty(x, y) = 0$ (where $x$ may be equal to $y$)$\}$ for each point $x \in C^n$. Will have some more explicit?

Comment: I've given an answer below. For the future, you should always include what you have tried in the question body so that people can see where you are confused (it's also officially required on this site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but are confusing the definition of your pseudometics: the elements of your spaces are equivalence classes of functions given by $\{y\in C^n:\tilde{d^j}(x,y)=0\}$. Again, $x$ and $y$ are *functions* in the preceding set. If it helps you remember/keep track, we could rewrite the classes as $\{g\in C^n:\tilde{d^j}(f,g)=0\}$, using variable letters more commonly associated with functions.

Now we plug in the definition of the $\tilde{d^j}$ seminorms to see that the elements of $C^n[0,1] / \tilde{d^j}$ are classes $\{g\in C^n:\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f^{(j)}(x)-g^{(j)}(x)|=0\}$. Notice that only now is $x$ a point.

Finally, we consider what this all means. If the maximum difference between two functions is zero, then the functions must be the same. So this is saying that our equivalence classes are classes of functions with the same $j^{th}$ derivative. And this means that they must differ by a function whose $j^{th}$ derivative is zero. These functions are just polynomials of degree less than $j$.

In conclusion, the elements of your space are classes $\{ f(x)+p_j(x):p_j(x) \text{ is a polynomial of degree less than } j\}$

Comment: I don't understand this "If the maximum difference between two functions is zero, then the functions must be the same(??). So this is saying that our equivalence classes are classes of functions with the same jth derivative(??). And this means that they must differ by a function whose jth derivative is zero. These functions are just polynomials of degree less than j." But thanks for answer : $\{ f(x)+p_j(x):p_j(x) \text{ is a polynomial of degree less than } j\}$

Comment: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ never differ by more than zero, aren't they the same function?

Comment: For every $x$, $f(x)-g(x)=0$, so $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x$, and $f$ and $g$ are the same function.

Comment: Applying this argument to $f^{(j)}(x)$ and $g^{(j)}(x)$, because that's what the definition of the norm tells us to do, we see that $f^{(j)}(x)=g^{(j)}(x)$, so the classes are of functions with the same jth derivative.

Comment: It is far more important that you understand the proof than that you have the answer; the answer is meaningless if you don't understand the arguments that led to it.

Comment: Thanks professor. You help me. The essential that I note is the part "$f^{(j)}(x)=g^{(j)}(x)$, so the classes are of functions with the same $j^{th}$ derivative". The strange in your previous observation is that if: $f(x)=x, g(x)=x^2$, then $\max |f^{(10)}(x)-g^{(10)}(x)|=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Hence your affirmation "For every x, f(x)−g(x)=0, so f(x)=g(x) for every x, and f and g are the same function" is true but not necessary.

Comment: Oh no, I'm sorry. I'm not saying $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same function there. There, it's $f^{(10)}(x)$ and $g^{(10)}(x)$ that are the same, because they're what's inside the max.